# arning json and its nullpointer exception while getting JSONarray

Tags: android, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

I am learning JSON and its parsing in android using same code/example
    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

but while implementing and running its give null pointer exception

while getting JSON i.e on     `contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);`

```
  JSONArray contacts = null;
 private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";


 public void initParsing()
 {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_song);
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
     try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            System.out.println("---getJSON");
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                 System.out.println("---times");
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
//                  R.layout.list_item,
//                  new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
//                          R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

       // setListAdapter(adapter);
    //  listView.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, TAG_NAME)); // setting the adapter


 }
```

Comment: show us the logcat output and where exactly the app is crashing

Comment: did you seriously commented on your own question a minute after asking it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void initParsing()
 {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_song);
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
     try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            System.out.println("---getJSON");
           if(json != null && json.has("contacts")){
            contacts = json.getJSONArray("contacts");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                 System.out.println("---times");
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
//                  R.layout.list_item,
//                  new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
//                          R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

       // setListAdapter(adapter);
    //  listView.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, TAG_NAME)); // setting the adapter


 }
```

Comment: if i write else part of    if(json != null && json.has("contacts"))    it is going in that    but looking at the json by hitting that link it has the contacts....  can anyone explain what is happening here

Comment: Could you tell me what is the use of else part, if you have contacts JSONARRAY only then there is need to parse the response, isn't it?

Comment: Hey friend the problem is resolve many thanks to you and others

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the json array name is right..try using

```
contacts = json.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

Comment: by hitting the link from where i am getting JSON array, it has the same

Comment: no change same issue, problem is somewhere else or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You must use this:

```
contacts = json.optJSONArray("array name");
```

this will return an array if your response having an array otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion brother but issue remains the same

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an array values.

Comment: Could you post your JSON response.

Comment: you **must** not. both methods exist, in some case test for null is good, in some other, you expect an exception because your app cannot run without data.

Comment: thanks a lot friend the issue is resolved now.... i did little research and effort by own and solution came.. thanks a lot